# Build a Curator client with CuratorWatcher

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I need use Curator client to replace the zk client:

```
zooKeeper = new ZooKeeper(zkConn, 10000, new Watcher() {
        @Override
        public void process(WatchedEvent event) {
          if (event.getState() == KeeperState.SyncConnected) {
            log("connected.");
            Latch.countDown();
          } else if (event.getState() == KeeperState.Disconnected) {
            log("disconnected.");
          }
        }
      });
```

I cannot find any Curator client constructor with CuratorWatcher. May I ask how to use CuratorWatcherto implement the above code?

Although I have an ieda:

```
    curator = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkConn, retryPolicy);
    curator.start();
    curator.getData().usingWatcher(new CuratorWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void process(WatchedEvent event) throws Exception {
         if (event.getState() == KeeperState.SyncConnected) {
            log("connected.");
            Latch.countDown();
         } else if (event.getState() == KeeperState.Disconnected) {
            log("disconnected.");
         }
  }});
```

I don't know if it is correct, because as far as I know the curator.getData() shold build with `.forPath(path)` at the end. Should I use curator.getState() in stead, as the curator client is just stated there is certainly no data to get.

Any advice is welcome, thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Implement it in this way:

```
curator.getConnectionStateListenable().addListener(new ConnectionStateListener() {

      public void stateChanged(CuratorFramework curator, ConnectionState state) {
          if (state == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
            log("connected.");
            Latch.countDown();
          } else if (state == ConnectionState.LOST) {
            log("disconnected.");
          }
      }
    });
    curator.start();
```